# mySqli Bind Parameter LIKE with Wildcard

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm having issues binding the `LIKE` with Wildcard into my prepared statement in MySQLi. I tried both the following methods below as shown & concat.(updated with @fancyPants input)

- Is there a way so that I can view my own SQL statement after the binding happens?
- How do I bind it properly to get the result I want ?

It works without the LIKE statement.

I could only pull out data from using a certain search term. Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
$str = $_POST["searchstr"];


    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $price=$_POST['price'];


        if(!empty($_POST['chkbx']))
        {
            foreach($_POST['chkbx'] as $selected)
            {


                $sql= 'SELECT bookTitle, bookPrice FROM nbc_book WHERE catID LIKE "%'.$selected.'%" AND bookTitle LIKE "%'.$str.'%" AND bookPrice < ?';
                $stmt=mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"i",$price);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $bookTitle, $bookPrice); 
                while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                     echo $bookTitle.$bookPrice."<br>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$searchStr =  'oracle';
$sql= 'SELECT bookTitle, bookPrice FROM nbc_book WHERE catID LIKE ? AND bookTitle LIKE "%'.$searchStr.'%" AND bookPrice < ?';
$stmt=mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ssi",$selected,$price);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $bookTitle, $bookPrice); 
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $bookTitle;
}
```

Comment: updated the code with your input, but it gives this error. "Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() [function.mysqli-stmt-bind-param]: Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in /var/www/search.php on line 108"

Comment: Fixed it, you can remove the `$searchStr` parameter in `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`. Forgot about that.

Comment: sorry bro couldn't give u rep i only have a pathetic 6 reps ):

Comment: I have made amendments based on your advice. somehow i could only manage to pull out data from my sql database when i search for 'oracle' specifically. is there anything wrong with my code? thank you.

Comment: Well, it searches for whatever is in `$_POST["searchstr"]`. This part of your code is not visible to me. And maybe I can't help you, actually I'm no programmer, I'm more the SQL and database guy. In my answer I was just guessing. Since your question is different from your original question, it would be best to create a new question. See, we invest work in answering your question, then editing the question to adjust a whole new problem is considered kind of rude here.