# Search on mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm have been working on a website for a class context and I'm doing a search field that goes to mysql database table and return a matched result.

I make this code but its not working and the error is like "Array to string conversion" I have searched for hours and cant find a solution. Here is my code:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST) ){

    $searchstring['string'] = $_POST['string'];
    $productManager = new ProductManagement();

    $results = $productManager->searchProduct($searchstring);

    if (!$results) {
        echo "nothing found";
    } else {
        while($row = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

            echo '


            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="'. $row ['image'] .'" alt="" width="320px" weight="150px">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h4 class="pull-right">€'. $row ['price'] .'</h4>
                        <h4><a href="#">'. $row ['name'] .'</a>
                        </h4>
                        <p><strong>Size:</strong> '. $row ['size'] .'</p>
                        <p class="pull-right"><a class="btn btn-info" href="view.php?id='. $row ['id_shirt'] .'" role="button">Ver</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            ';

        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
public function searchProduct($searchstring)
{
    $results = $this->_database->performQuery("SELECT * FROM `shirts` WHERE name LIKE '%".$searchstring."%'");
    return($results);

}
```

I hope you can help me thanks!

Comment: What line is causing the error?

Comment: Like the error says, you created array `searchstring` then tried to use it like a string in your sql.

Comment: is on public function, at the the query line.

Comment: Per Digital Chris, `$searchstring['string'] = $_POST['string'];` should probably be `$searchstring = $_POST['string'];`

Comment: Keep in mind your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should be using prepared statements with bound parameters.

Comment: How should I convert it in a string?

Comment: @RuiParedes You don't need to convert it to a string. It already is a string. Adding `['string']` after a variable does not make it a string. If you want to explicitly convert something to a string you would do: `$str = (string) $int;`. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php. Just do what Andrew has above.

Comment: its working now, with a simple solution I'm so newbie! many thanks to all of you guys :)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use this:

```
$searchstring = $_POST['string'];
```

insted of this:

```
$searchstring['string'] = $_POST['string'];
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, you can fix this one of two ways.

Either make `$searchstring` a string like:

```
$searchstring = $_POST['string'];
```

or change your sql to use the array value you chose:

```
$results = $this->_database->performQuery("SELECT * FROM shirts WHERE name LIKE '%".$searchstring['string']."%'");
```

Comment: This does not address the SQL injection vulnerability. You should never put user-supplied data directly into a query.

Comment: As @Mike mentioned, for any production-worthy code you want to parameterize your queries like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543097/mysqli-bind-parameter-like-with-wildcard

Comment: Thank you I didnt know about that and make sense, I will keep this in mind :)